# Flutter: release apk are not installed on android emulator

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, apk

I am trying to make apk from flutter application so after creating flutter project :

```
flutter create release_app_test
```

According [official](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) site i create a signing key.

This is a complete build gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.release_app_test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

I made apk by this command:

```
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test
$ flutter build apk --split-per-abi
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      11.4s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (5.1MB).
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (5.4MB).
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk (5.6MB).
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test
$
```

After creating apk now i want to install that by adb command but i got this error:

```
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Software/Linux/Android/SDK/platform-tools
$ adb install /mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk 
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install /mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Software/Linux/Android/SDK/platform-tools
$ adb install /mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk 
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install /mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Software/Linux/Android/SDK/platform-tools
$ adb install /mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk 
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install /mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Software/Linux/Android/SDK/platform-tools
```

None of apks are not installed.

After googling i added to module build.gradle and within Android block

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

After added this script i got this result :

```
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test
$ flutter build apk --split-per-abi
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 44KB to 35KB: Removed 20%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      13.6s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (5.1MB).
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk (5.6MB).
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test
```

The apks are built:

```
tazik@mx-linux:/mnt/Project/Flutter/my_practises/release_app_test/build/app/outputs/apk/release
$ ls -l --block-size=MB
total 28MB
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6MB Apr 28 12:25 app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16MB Apr 28 12:25 app-universal-release.apk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6MB Apr 28 12:25 app-x86_64-release.apk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1MB Apr 28 12:25 app-x86-release.apk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1MB Apr 28 12:25 output.json
```

Just app-x86-release.apk installed but it is corrupted and it can not runs on emulator. Because as you can see it's size is 1MB..

And my flutter sdk version is : **flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable**

Answer (score 0):

As of now we are having some issues in installing the flutter release fat apk by drag and drop in android emulator.

However you can check by generating supported ABI's and its corresponding emulator. I have not tried, but you may give it a shot if you need atmost. Details can be found in the below link.

[flutter issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28432)

Comment: This problem is just not for emulator , I can not install this apk on real devices @RaguSwaminathan

Comment: Then the APK may be corrupted or you need to enable some developer option in your mobile like ''enable install from unknown sources''.